# GNU Arm Toolchain - Minimum Installation

Tags: arm, gnu

I am trying to generate a binary from source for a cortex m0 and using the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain for that along with a simple makefile.

It is possible for me to use just **arm-none-eabi-gcc** to generate my elf file and then **arm-none-eabi-objcopy** to generate a binary. All good till this point. On copying just these two files to another machine with no installed toolchain, it seems that these files call various other binaries like **cc1** for example. This got me wondering, how can I create a minimal package to generate binaries for a cortex m0.

The complete installation of the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain is around 700MB. I have a feeling that I should be able to generate simple binaries with very little.

Does anyone have any information if that is possible. Are there already smaller toolchains that I might not be aware of?

Comment: There are endless examples of this, what problems are you having?

Comment: 700MB is nothing, what platform are you on that you cant find space for 700MB?

Comment: no doubt there are other toolchains, which ones have you tried thus far?

Comment: I haven't tried any other toolchains as I could not find much. 700 MB might not be the main issue here. Installing the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain needs adding path variables and so on. I would like to make a simple installer where all necessary binaries are copied to a folder and all is good to go. Having a minimal set would hence be very helpful here.

Comment: A minimum package is the binary.  You need to specify what exactly you want as **possible** to create.  So your question is a little unfair as you know the answer as to what you want, but no one else does...  However, the concept of what you are asking is good.

Comment: Sorry that the question was a bit unfair, that was not really my intention. After having figured out what I exactly wanted (i.e. a ready binary from a single source file) it beacame a lot easier to look for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After finding a very helpful tip [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203575) I was able to use **gcc**, **cc1** and **as** alone to successfully generate a binary file frome a single independat c source.

The key was to enable verbose output to see the dependancies and then use just those. I will now try to expand the scope to slightly large projects to see how it works. The final size of all the binaries required is less than 30 MB.

Answer (score 0):

There is much to unpack here.

The cortex-m0 is an ARM thumb machine, and based on the armv6m architecture.  It supports the thumb instruction set going back to the ARM7TDMI (armv4t) with a couple of dozen thumb2 extensions, look it up yourself, and count them.  You can basically use a toolchain that can create thumb binaries for the last 20 years or so.  Plenty of toolchains to evaluate.

Likewise, thus far, the cortex-m0 or more correctly armv6m, from an instruction set perspective as in toolchain output, is a reverse compatible base for the other cortex-m architectures.  So you can build code telling the toolchain cortex-m0 and have it execute on cortex-m3,m4,m7,m8...Not necessarily optimized as armv7m added another 150 or so thumb2 extensions.  Same goes for using armv4t should work for all.  Note that gnu, or let's say, gcc has dropped support for armv4t, the apt-gotten versions still have it but at some point when they catch up to the stable releases it is gone.

IMO the term toolchain is basically compiler, assembler and linker.  NOT C library.  You get into that with an SDK.  So do you want a C library, that adds a whole other chunk of disk space and complicates the construction of bare-metal programs, which I won't get into as the linker script is married to the bootstrap code which is specific to the design of the C library and/or SDK.  Likewise with other typical SDK items for a specific MCU/family is chip vendor code to support the chip.  Remember that almost none of your code is related to the arm core, it is all about the chip, which is not from arm.  Today you can trivially extract the arm core and replace it with an risc-v core, roll your own or buy one of the many available.  Arm is like the language/alphabet, you can write a math textbook in English or French or ... and have the same content.

In the gnu world gcc is just a wrapper/launcher program as you have begun to figure out.  Unless you tell it not to, it calls a preprocessor, the now single C file is fed to the compiler.  Which generates an assembly language program then it calls the assembler to turn that into an object.  Repeat for each file on the command line and then call the linker.  If you tell it compile only then it gets you to the object level.  The preprocessor and C compiler are technically binaries you can call but not really something you would.  The assembler and linker are in the gnu world from a whole other project, separate from the compiler(s), called binutils.  Binutils has a ton of useful tools, not just the assembler and linker, IMO is what separates gnu from its competitors and in many cases you can use binutils on binaries created by other toolchains.

You can easily create binaries for a cortex-m mcu with binutils only in assembly language without C code.  You cannot have/use gcc without binutils or some replacement.

You did not specify a chip nor family, some vendors alias address zero, for example so they can have a factory bootloader (st, nxp, ...) and the proper address for the application flash is not at zero.  A number of chip vendors using cortex-ms have not aliased and you build your binary for zero, I will just build for zero.  But understand you have to build the binary to match the hardware.

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.global vectors
vectors:
.word 0x20000800
.word reset

.thumb_func
reset:
    b .



arm-none-eabi-as flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0 flash.o -o flash.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d flash.elf 

flash.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <vectors>:
   0:   20000800    .word   0x20000800
   4:   00000009    .word   0x00000009

00000008 <reset>:
   8:   e7fe        b.n 8 <reset>
```

That is a somewhat minimal binary that works on any cortex-m to date.

Only using as and ld and then objcopy if you need it.

You will really want to control the linker with a script so.

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x100
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x100
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > ram
}
```

Is the linker script I use, I do not use .data and do not expect .bss to be zeroed (non-standard C).  I avoid the (rwx) stuff in linker scripts, but your experience may be different.  Folks tend to grossly over-complicate their linker scripts which I will never understand.

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o -o flash.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D flash.elf > flash.list

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <vectors>:
   0:   20000800    andcs   r0, r0, r0, lsl #16
   4:   00000009    andeq   r0, r0, r9

00000008 <reset>:
   8:   e7fe        b.n 8 <reset>
```

If you want to then add C to this. I will make it a little more complicated, but still somewhat minimal.

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x100
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x100
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > ram
}

.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.global vectors
vectors:
.word 0x20000800
.word reset
.word nada
.word nada

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b .

.thumb_func
nada:
    b .

.globl ping
.thumb_func
ping:
    b .



extern void ping ( unsigned int );

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    for(ra=0;ra<10;ra++) ping(ra);
    return(0);
}

arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.o -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary notmain.elf notmain.bin


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <vectors>:
   0:   20000800    andcs   r0, r0, r0, lsl #16
   4:   00000011    andeq   r0, r0, r1, lsl r0
   8:   00000017    andeq   r0, r0, r7, lsl r0
   c:   00000017    andeq   r0, r0, r7, lsl r0

00000010 <reset>:
  10:   f000 f804   bl  1c <notmain>
  14:   e7fe        b.n 14 <reset+0x4>

00000016 <nada>:
  16:   e7fe        b.n 16 <nada>

00000018 <ping>:
  18:   e7fe        b.n 18 <ping>
    ...

0000001c <notmain>:
  1c:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
  1e:   2400        movs    r4, #0
  20:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  22:   3401        adds    r4, #1
  24:   f7ff fff8   bl  18 <ping>
  28:   2c0a        cmp r4, #10
  2a:   d1f9        bne.n   20 <notmain+0x4>
  2c:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  2e:   bd10        pop {r4, pc}
```

Many toolchains including GNU will add extra stuff to the binary if it sees a main(), so to avoid that my entry point is not called main, again non-standard.

If you want to then add chip libraries or a C library then what you do from there depends on the libraries as to what you have to add.

Clang/llvm I am familiar with.  It was rough to support as each major version they change their command line options/details making it not possible to have a common source that builds from year to year.  I have code written 20 plus years ago for GNU that still builds (or let's say I can make one set of sources and makefile that builds for major GNU versions for decades).

I recently was able to come back to supporting llvm by treating it GNU style and building a binary for the target, so for example build a clang/llvm toolchain for armv6m, one for armv7m, etc.  By doing this I can technically not rely on GNU binutils.  If you apt-get clang/llvm then you will get a linker, etc for the host platform not target.  It is cmake based so it takes a long time to build, quite painful.  As with any claims from llvm, gcc, gas, and GNU linker script compatibility is not 100%, but close enough to struggle through.  In general one should avoid gee-whiz parts of the language as well as use as little non-language specific things from a toolchain as possible (linker scripts, inline assembly, directives, etc).

The world is no longer they way it used to be for bare-metal where there were a long list of tools vendors (that had really good tools).  Now we have some tools that are just okay that cover a wide range of targets and platforms.  Gcc for example has been producing worse code version after version the 3.x.x/4.x.x versions were about the best for arm/thumb. clang/llvm has not "introduced" as many missed optimizations over time as GNU (things that it did know how to remove, it now leaves in, including some baffling ones (you are on the site where this has been demonstrated, look around)).

700MB is nothing, even as part of an SDK download if you are trying to package it all together as some form of product.  If you were making some sort of SDK product though you would not be asking this question...

Certainly you can look through the directory structure and see the arm-whatever-gcc and then there is a gcc without the arm-whatever- and can rename/remove these (the whole set in the directory) and see which are used or not for your particular builds.  And then contemplate removing those files one by one.  If you are not using a GNU C library then don't build it, the default linker scripts and other items you can remove.  There may be arm versions of libraries and thumb, that whole arm soft float, arm hard float, thumb soft float, thumb hard float for gcclib or a C lib is painful from a building of a GNU toolchain perspective, but it could mean you have things multiplied that you simply do not need for your target toolchain and can remove either as part of the build process or after the fact by deleting files/directories.

I do not understand the desire to chop up the toolchain to make it smaller, but you did not indicate your target size nor what parts of the toolchain you wanted to remove.  You should start with the build configuration and go from there, you might, for example, be able to remove a number of binutils things you do not need, as mentioned above can control gcclib, and target that to your specific core.

Comment: I am initially looking to build just a simple compiler-linker-objdump toolchain. The idea is to compile very primitive single file code without referencing any libraries. I imagine this should be possible by keeping a dozen or so utilities in a folder. All I wish to know is if something like that is readily available or if I have to figure out the details myself.